# Is there a way to make the spell magic tattoo permanent?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Is there a way to make the spell *magic tattoo* (*Spell Compendium* 55) last forever? The feat Extend Spell only makes it last 48 hours.

I only need the *magic tattoo* for myself. I can't cast the spell, but I can pay to have another cast it on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You would have to work it out with the Game Master

The spell **Permanency**, from Player's Handbook makes a few selected spells permanent, however there is also a suggestion that other spells could also be made permanent, if Game Master would allow it.

> The DM may allow other selected spells to  be  made  permanent. Researching  this possible application of a spell costs as much  time  and money  as  independently researching the selected spell (see the Dungeon Master’s Guide for details). If the DM has already determined that the application is not possible, the research automatically fails. Note that you never learn what is possible except by the success or failure of your research.